# Why do my GitHub actions say "deploying to dev"? Can I customize this text?

Tags: github-actions

When running, my GitHub actions often display "deploying to dev" or something similar next to the progress bar. This is not text I have entered. Apparently the action guesses this from the action (e.g. the `environment` parameter).

Sometimes it guesses correctly, but often it guesses wrong. Many of my actions do not actually "deploy".

Is it possible to customize this text?

Comment: Could you share the action you're using or the workflow that display this message?